# Systematic version of "rummage"

Tags: vocabulary

What is an "antonym" of "rummage?" I cannot seem to figure out a word which means "searching systematically and tidily through a mass or receptacle."

Answer (score 4):

That would be...

> [***sift***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sift#sift_5) or [***sift through***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sift-through_1) - examine information, documents etc., in order to find what you are looking for
>
> *Sift every grain of information until you find the answer.
>
>   He spent hours sifting through all the documents relating to the case.
>
>   They sifted through the rubble, searching for signs of life.*

Comment: alternatively `combed`?

Comment: @user13107: Yes, Edwin's *combed* is also fine. It doesn't seem quite right for my first example above, but maybe that's just me. Also note Google Books figures for *sifted through the papers*:4850, with *combed*:92 (without *through*, the corresponding figures are 188 and 255). But for an expression, his *go through with a fine-tooth comb* is, as he says, "spot on".

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad you put the scare quotes round 'antonym'.

The only single word I can think of for 'search [X] thoroughly' is 'comb'. Which has various senses that you might not want. And would only work in certain situations (ie only have certain collocates).

If an expression will do, 'go through with a fine-tooth comb' is spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Scrutinized? I scrutinized the bunch of papers.

Examined? I examined the pile of things on the floor.

Scoured? I scoured through the documents to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to toss "sort" or "sort through" into the ring as well.  It implies a structured approach, rather than a random one.

Answer (score 1):

There's always something like *inspected*, as in "He inspected the contents of the desk thoroughly."

*Enumerate* will work in some contents.  And as bib mentions, *catalog* can work as well.

Further possibilities include: *pore over*, *peruse*, *scan* .

It is also worth noting that *rummage* can also be used to mean in a sense close to what you are looking for (in addition to the unsystematic version you describe):

From the ***OED*** :

> (rummage, v.) trans.
>    To scrutinize, examine minutely, investigate.
>   [...]
>  1864   *J. H. Burton* **Scot Abroad I.** v. 305,   I am inclined to concur
>   in Pasquier's silence, having rummaged his ‘Recherches de la France’.
>   1907   **Life** Sept. 71   The shallow mind rummages the fields of fiction
>   with a morbid desire to see how this or that ends. 
>   1975   **Gen. Syst**.20 108/1   The search for causes must first rummage the material factors, not the social-organizational or ideological factors. 
>   2004 *W. M. Billings* **Sir William Berkeley** p. xi,   I rummaged the records in
>   search of a deeper understanding of seventeenth-century Virginians.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *[ransack](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ransack)*, in the non-plundering sense:-

> To search or examine thoroughly.
>
> To search through every part of (a house, box, etc); examine thoroughly
>
> To search thoroughly or vigorously through (a house, receptacle, etc.).

Comment: I think *on average* the emphasis is more on "vigorously" with this one. And that the primary connotation is actually the mess left behind after a place (not usually a "container" such as a paper or electronic filing system) has been (often, unsuccessfully) ransacked.